# Power BI Time duration

Tags: time, microsoft-powerbi

I have time stamp data I'm working with. I have data I get in a excel file that I'm uploading to Power BI that has Production Hours field. This field is the amount of time it took to do a task. I have it as hh:mm:ss in excel so ex) 7:40:00 or 0:20:00 means they worked for 7 hours and 40 mins or 20 min. When I bring this into Power BI it turns it into a time. So example becomes 7:40:00 AM and 12:20:00 AM

How to turn this into a duration and not a time ?

Answer (score 0):

I would use Change Type (button in each column heading, or right-click, or use Transform ribbon) to change the type to **Duration**. This should replace any existing Change Type step.